# why does $\int_0^\pi \cos t(\sin t)^2 dt$ evaluate to $0$ when given the substitution $u = \sin t$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\pi \cos t(\sin t)^2 dt$$
This evaluates to $0$ if I make the substitution $u = \sin t$ because the integral becomes $\int_0^0$. But on the other hand if I use a calculator and evaluate this integral I get $3.14 \times 10^{-3}$ . Why does this happen ? What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please also check your calculator and the input

Comment: I didn't quite understand what that meant. That's why I asked this question 

Comment: Your substitution is correct and the integral is indeed equal to $0$.

Comment: @Fakemistake you are correct

Comment: I must say sorry guys, from the deepest part of my heart. It was a mistake that I had on the calculator. I had been using degrees as unit for angles instead of radians. Thank you for all your effort. I am planning to delete the post.

Comment: Not sure you can delete it with so many answers ...

Comment: Yep seems like that

Comment: Deleting it? I would regret that. Lots of people can learn from this. Also from your "blunder" (btw, we make them all) ;-).

Answer (score 3):

Note the antiderivative of $f (t)=\cos t (\sin t)^2$ is $F (t)=\frac{1}{3} (\sin t)^3 + C$ ($C $ const, e.g. $C=0$) and the conditions of the FTC are fulfilled, so your integral is just $F(\pi)-F (0)=\frac {1}{3}((\sin\pi)^3-(\sin 0)^3)=0$, and it *is* 0 after all.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have doubts, just make the "more trusted" substitution $t=u- \frac {\pi}2$, you'll get $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin u(\cos t)^2 du=0$ because the function is odd, therefore your substitution is right.

Answer (score 0):

Things might go wrong because $\sin$ is not monotone on the interval $(0,\pi)$.

Try it again with the RHS of :$$\int_0^{\pi}\dots dt=\int_0^{\frac12\pi}\dots dt+\int_{\frac12\pi}^{\pi}\dots dt$$

On the smaller intervals $\sin$ is monotone.

Apart from that also note that: $$\int_{\frac12\pi}^{\pi}\cos t(\sin t)^2dt=-\int_0^{\frac12\pi}\cos(\pi-t)(\sin(\pi-t))^2d(\pi-t)=-\int_0^{\frac12\pi}\cos t(\sin t)^2dt$$

Comment: but then again when you make the substitution you get 0

Comment: Well, I expect that to be the correct answer then. It agrees with the other method mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

We should make use of the following change of formula theorem, I adopted from Introduction to Analysis, William R. Wade:

Let $\phi$ be continuously differentiable on a closed, nondegenerate interval $[a,b]$. If $\phi'$ is nonzero on $(a,b)$ and if $f$ is integrable on $[c,d]=\phi[a,b]$, then $f\circ\phi\cdot|\phi'|$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, and 
\begin{align*}
\int_{c}^{d}f(t)dt=\int_{a}^{b}f(\phi(x))\cdot|\phi'(x)|dx.
\end{align*}

Return to your question, the $\sin$ which is the role of $\phi$, its derivative, $\cos$, is zero somewhere on $(0,\pi)$, but if we restrict to $(0,\pi/2)$, then it is safe to use the theorem.

Comment: Okay, I see that the integral is zero, but I think it is safer if we use the theorem.